# Get previous / next post of the same category

Tags: cakephp, categories

So, what I have is a page which displays a post. Posts are gathered into projects. And, on this page, in addition to the post, I'ld to display the previous and next post of the same project. So, I have this in my controller :

```
$this->set("post", $this->Post->find("first", array("conditions" => array("Post.id" => $id), "contain" => array("User", "Project", "Project.Post" => array("id", "image", "title"), "Comment", "Comment.User" => array("id", "username", "mail"), "Comment.User.Post" => array("id", "image", "title")))));
$this->set("neighbors", $this->Post->find("neighbors", array("field" => "id", "value" => $id)));
```

The problem is that it get the previous and next post from all the post, not only the ones of the same project.

So, if you could helping me a bit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming Post belongsTo Project and Project hasMany Post.

You would just need to add an extra condition:

```
$post = $this->Post->find("first", ...); // this is your first find call, assign it to a var instead

$neighbors = $this->Post->find('neighbors', array(
    'field' => 'id', 
    'value' => $id,
    'conditions' => array(
        'Post.project_id' => $post['Post']['project_id'],
    ),
));
$this->set(compact('post', 'neighbors'));
```

I haven't tried it, but looking at the source, findNeighbors does honor the `conditions` key.

Comment: Yep, I was trying something like that too, the problem is that I don't know how to the $projectId from the original post inside the controller.